# How do I replace my HTML Submit button with an ActionLink?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, .net-4.0

I have a view with a submit button. I also have a few ActionLinks on the view. Everything is function right now but I want to repalce the ugly button with an ActionLink to match the rest of the controls that are part of the view.

I'm new to MVC. So far, I tried converting the button to a link but I need to post the form, which an actionlink wont do without some other code.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, this can be resolved with CSS along the lines of

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" class="submit-actionlink" />

.submit-actionlink
{
    background-color: red; /* colour to match background of other action links*/
    color: #FFF /* colour to match background of other action links */
    margin:0;
    padding:0;

    /* the ffg 3 lines are the important part*/
    border: 0px solid #FFF; 
    text-decoration: underline; 
    cursor:pointer;
    /* and whatever else */

}
```

(Note: I used red and white colours above so that you can visually see whats going on, will need to change though based on your look and feel)

Answer (score 0):

If you use JQuery validation you can do this and still have client-side validation triggered.

```
<a href="#" onclick="$(this).parents('form').submit();">Submit</a>
```